# python PyUserInput import error

Tags: python-2.7

Hi I am trying to download PyUserInput, I downloaded it using pip and there were no errors. When I try to import it into a file in give me an error which I do not understand. I have a basic understanding of python and pip.Any help will be much appreciated.I have pasted the error I get below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from pymouse import PyMouse
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymouse/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
from .x11 import PyMouse, PyMouseEvent
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymouse/x11.py", line 16, in <module>
    from Xlib.display import Display
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 26, in <module>
from six import create_unbound_method
ImportError: cannot import name create_unbound_method
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem on old raspberry pi image and upgrading six solved the issue for me:

sudo pip install six --upgrade